# Sonarqube Coverage Randomly Drops with Same Commit

Tags: sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline

We have a Jenkins pipeline that (as one of its steps) runs Sonarqube. Right now it insists that coverage must be 90% or higher, which is what we want to maintain. Unfortunately, sometimes the coverage it "perceives" will randomly drop. For example, if our coverage has been around 95%, it will report coverage of 70-80%.

However, re-running the *exact same commit* will then yield the correct coverage of 95% or whatever. We've seen this problem a few times. In the specific example I just encountered, we went from 74% for the first time the commit was checked to 94% for the 2nd time.

Expected: The same commit should consistently produce the same level of coverage in Sonarqube.

Actual: Sometimes coverage will vary substantially (20% or even a bit more) with the same commit.

Comment: Do you use different compiler flags or release / debug builds like in C++ or other languages? Optimization can sometimes make a huge difference in code coverage.

Comment: SonarQube doesn't compute the coverage, but reads the report file of external tools. So it's either the coverage tool is flaky, or SonarQube doesn't import the report correctly. The first scenario is more likely. I suggest to compare the content of the coverage report in the two cases (correct and incorrect reported on SonarQube) to narrow down the source of the problem.